# Python - Find, match, sort and append based on unique values

Tags: python, csv, data-mining

I have a CSV File with two columns which specify account linking structures.
The issue that I have is that there is a double reverse entry for each of these links.

Example

```
Column1 Column2
12513   52188
52188   12513
```

The other issue that I also have is that there could be more entries which specify another linkage to and from the same account numbers

```
Column1 Column2
12513   52188
52188   12513
52188   19922
19922   52188
19922   12812
12812   19922
18216   59888
59888   18216
3856   59888
59888   3856
```

As you can see all of the accounts are somehow interlinked between one another, the output that I am looking for should create one master account (probably the account with the lowest value ) linked to slave accounts and also remove the double reverse entry.

Example output from data above:

```
Column1 Column2
12513   52188
12513   19922
12513   12812
3856    59888
3856    18216
```

The file contains around 20,000 lines with, 
please note there isn't only one master account.

Comment: you expected output is unclear

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/NiallCosgrove/kayboxa`

Comment: Its up on github now, to avoid copy/paste errors.  I tested it on 20000 pairs of random numbers, took quarter of an hour. Let me know how you get on

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help. If you could recommend any good reading material for someone starting out in python i would really appreciate it.

Comment: That's a hard question to answer. It really depends on your prior programming experience. There are millions on the web, choose one you can understand that pushes you a little.  hackerrank.com is a great place for practicing your skills. Definitely worth doing the coding challenges there. I'm not allowed to ask you to vote on my answer, but if I was I would ;) - Trying to make 1K rep by the end of the year.  Happy to know the job is finally done. Thanks btw for doing the edit and re-tag I asked for - Gave you an upvote for that.

Comment: Thank you once more, I tried to earlier but didn't have enough rep to vote.  Now I do, hope you get to that 1k. Happy holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is:
Given a data set in the form

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
3,1
6,5
5,7
```

Identify the chains `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4` and `5 -> 6 -> 7`
And output them as

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
5,6
5,7
```

Here is a working solution in python. (Happy Holidays)

To run it use `python thisfile.py yourdata.csv > output.csv`

You, of course, will need to have python3 installed.
There are plenty of comments in the code. I gave no thought at all to efficiency, so put the kettle on - it will take about 15 mins or so to complete.

If you want it to be faster, its the list.append() calls that take the time. Using numpy would probably speed things up but I didn't want to add extra dependencies.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Output from your example data is:

> ```
> 3856 , 18216
> 3856 , 59888
> 12513 , 12812
> 12513 , 19922
> 12513 , 52188
> ```

```
import csv
import sys


def flatten(l):
    return list(set([item for subl in l for item in subl]))

def main():
    # read the csv                                                                                      
    raw_data = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as so_data:
        lst = csv.reader(so_data)
        for row in lst:
            raw_data.append(row)

        data = []
        for i in raw_data:
            data.append([int(i[0].strip()), int(i[1].strip())])

        #set keys to uniq elements from col1 and col2                                                   
        keys1 = list(set([i[0] for i in data]))
        keys2 = list(set([i[1] for i in data]))
        keys = list(set(keys1 + keys2))

        # find the subchains for each key                                                               
        subchains = {}
        for key in keys:
            found = [k for k in data if key in k]
            found = flatten(found)
            subchains[key] = found

        # This is the tricky bit                                                                        
        # we need to follow each element of the subchains looking                                       
        # for new links - we are done for a key when the list doesn't grow                              
        chain, links = [], []
        chain_dict = {}
        for key in keys:
            links.append(subchains[key])
            links = flatten(links)
            done = False
            size = len(links)
            while not done:
                for i in links:
                    # find subchain for i                                                               
                    for e in subchains[i]:
                        chain.append(e)
                        chain = list(set(chain))
                        chain.sort()
                if len(chain) > size:
                    done = False
                    size = len(chain)
                else:
                    done = True
                    chain_dict[key] = chain
                    chain, links = [], []

        # shorter chains will now be subsets of longer ones                                             
        # and those can be discarded                                                                    
        remove_list = []
        for i in keys:
            for j in keys:
                if set(chain_dict[j]) < set(chain_dict[i]):
                    remove_list.append(j)

        remove_list = list(set(remove_list))
        for i in remove_list:
            del chain_dict[i]

        # remove duplicate values from dict                                                             
        # it doesn't matter which key we remove                                                         
        # since we only output from value                                                               
        result = {}
        for key, value in chain_dict.items():
            if value not in result.values():
                result[key] = value

        # now output as per OP's request                                                                
        for k, v in result.items():
            v.sort()
            for i in v[1:]:
                print(v[0], ",", i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```